# Data transformation: stacking rows

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to transform a data frame on an specific way to perform some analysis. I have a data frame like this:

```
A <- data.frame(Date=c("A","A","B","B"), 
       Var1=c("A","B","A","B"), Var2=c(1,2,3,4), 
       Var3=c(5,6,7,8))
```

And I would like to get:

```
Result <- data.frame(Date=c("A","B"),
    Var4=c(1,2), Var5=c(5,6), 
    Var6=c(3,4), Var7=c(7,8))
```

I was trying with some functions in the reshape package but I could not do it. Some suggestions?

Comment: This vignette may be helpful: [Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html)

Comment: this is an unusual data format -- what you want is doable, but probably won't fit into a standard reshaping function ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
cbind(Date= unique(A$Date), do.call(cbind, split(A[-(1:2)], A$Date)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, as.list(unlist(.SD)) , .(Date=Var1), .SDcols = Var2:Var3]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for 2 variables. I tried to do it for 3 or more varibles but it dit not work.

Comment: @Diego Can you update your post with a small example and the expected output for 3 or more variables.